# When using Cache.Add, is an exception thrown if the key exists already or does it fail silently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

**I have read everywhere that the Add method fails if it already exists but does it throw an exception or does it fail silently?**

I am writing a multithreaded web application where it should not exist already and it will cause problems if I overwrite the cache, so I can't use the Insert method.

Would this be something I could do:

```
try
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("notifications", notifications, null,
      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(8),
      System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, null);
}
catch
{
    //do whatever if notifications already exist
}
```

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: isn't it easy enough to actually try it out yourself?

Comment: If I understand properly. I think you should check first whether a key with the same name already exists or not. If a key exists than don't add it. From msdn "Calls to this method will fail if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the Cache. To overwrite an existing Cache item using the same key parameter, use the Insert method."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`System.Web.Caching.Cache` is designed to be thread-safe in a multithreaded web application, and multiple threads may be in contention to add the same key to the cache.  So it depends on how you want to handle such race conditions.

- In many cases, you will be inserting immutable data into the cache and won't care which thread 'wins' the race.  So you can use `Add` or `Insert`.
- If you want "first one wins", use the `Add` method, if you want "last one wins (and overwrites)" use the `Insert` method.
- There is no point in checking for existence before inserting/adding.  Another thread may insert the item after your check and before you attempt to add/insert.
- Neither `Add` nor `Insert` with throw an exception if the key already exists.  It wouldn't make sense to do so as the Cache is designed for thread-safe insertion without locking.  `Add` will fail silently, and `Insert` wil overwrite.
- Incidentally, when reading from the Cache, don't check for existence then read:

  ```
  if (Cache["MyKey"] == null)
  {
      // ... handle missing value
  }
  else
  {
      // ... a race condition means the item may have been removed here
      // before you get a chance to read it

      MyType value = (MyType) Cache["MyKey"];
  }
  ```

  Instead, read the value from the cache and check for null:

  ```
  MyType value = Cache["MyKey"] as MyType; // for reference types
  if (value == null)
  {
      // ... handle missing value
  }
  ```

Comment: You're still dealing with a race condition here.

Comment: @J Torres, "You're still dealing with a race condition here." - yes there is a race condition here, but it's handled without locks.  The only case where I'd use a lock would be when generating the data to be inserted in the cache is so expensive that you want to ensure it's only incurred once.  And I've never been in that situation in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think I was over complicating the process behind it.  Quality answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that would be easy enough to test yourself, but it will throw an error.  A good utility function to use:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Places an item into the cache using absolute expiration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key of the item being inserted</param>
    /// <param name="item">Item to insert</param>
    /// <param name="expireTime">Absolute expiration time of the item</param>
    public static void InsertIntoCacheAbsoluteExpiration(string key, object item, DateTime expireTime)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (LOCK)
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(
                key,
                item,
                null,
                expireTime,
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                null);
        }
    }
```

Remove will not complain if the key doesn't exit.  If you would like to test if the key is already there, you can always check

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key) != null
```

As long as you use a locking variable, you should not run into an issue where your check says something is NOT in the cache, and it shows up between the check and the add.

Comment: I wouldn't use locking in this way - instead, use the `Insert` method, which is thread-safe and will overwrite an existing value.  See my answer.

Comment: I had never actually looked at Cache.Insert, thank you for the tip.  That does remove the need for the lock in this narrow view.  Using a lock in conjunction with a null-logic check is still necessary as you will run into race conditions without the lock.

Answer (score 0):

It fails silently.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;

        string object1 = "Object1";
        string object2 = "Object2";

        cache.Add(
            "Key", object1, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        cache.Add("Key", object2, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

        string cachedstring = (string)cache.Get("Key");

        Console.WriteLine(cachedstring);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output of this console app is `Object1`.